# modal window pop up leaving the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I'm using bootstrap modal class for popping up window when a user leaves the page.

And what I need is to pop up the window using javascript not the button.

So it does not work and I'm stuck with it, any help is appreciated

**Modal Window**

```
<div class="modal fade" data-toggle="draftModal" data-target="#draftModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <div>
                   <p>You are about to leave the deal. Would you like to save as a draft?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.onbeforeunload(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.modal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not override the `onbeforeunload` dialog with your own, so unfortunately you better be working with it as it's intended. The dialog will show, but also the once coming with the intended event. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx